# Selected Row Color is not changing Yellow In jqgrid

Tags: css, asp.net, jqgrid

hii Guys!!!!.
                  In MyJqgrid Background color of Selected Row is not changing to 'yellow' whereas while Hovering It is changing.I want to change the color to yellow on slection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'getGriddahico.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['id', 'username', 'ordinal', 'authcode', 'extension', 'trunk', 'dialnumber', 'dialdate', 'dialtime', 'duration', 'destination', 'price', 'toc'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'username', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'ordinal', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'authcode', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'extension', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'trunk', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'dialnumber', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'dialdate', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'dialtime', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'duration', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'destination', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'price', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                    { name: 'toc', width: 150, sortable: true, align: 'center' }
                ],
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 200, 300],
            pager: '#UsersGridPager',
            sortname: 'username',
            viewrecords: true,
            ignorecase:true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            autowidth: true,
            toppager: true,
            height: '100%'

        });

        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });

        jQuery("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: The problem with the **background color** is the problem of CSS and not only JavaScript code. If you use for example La Frog Theme of jQuery UI CSS then you will see mostly all in green color. The information which you posted is not enough to reproduce the problem which you describe.

Comment: @Oleg Sir plz tell me which css file to change ..Actually color is coming for same css file in grids\

Comment: The problem which you posted isn't common problem in jqGrid. If background color will be not changed on hovering or selecting of rows then you added **some your custom CSS which makes the problem**. If you don't post the CSS one can't help you to find **the origin** of the problem. In any way I think that you found already some *workaround* so the subject is closed now. Isn't so?

Comment: It's good news! You are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use css

```
 .ui-jqgrid-btable .ui-state-highlight { background: yellow; }
```

or

```
 .ui-jqgrid .ui-state-highlight { background: yellow; }
```

Comment: this worked for me:  div.ui-jqgrid .ui-state-highlight { background: lightblue; }